# How to use Rspec with Rails (or how to use it correctly)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I can't seem to get these Rspec tests to pass. I just don't know what exactly I'm doing wrong. Any advice?  These tests make sure that every hunt has an edit and delete link when admins are logged in.  I'm using FactoryGirl to generate a test admin user and a test hunt.

Here are the tests.

```
    describe "for users who are admins" do
      before(:each) do
        admin = FactoryGirl.create(:user, :email => "admin@example.com", :admin => true)
        test_sign_in(admin)
      end

    it "should show edit link" do
      get 'index'
      Hunt.each do |hunt|
        response.should have_selector('a', :href => "edit",
                                       :content => "edit")    
      end
    end

    it "should show delete link" do
      get 'index'
      Hunt.each do |hunt|
        response.should have_selector('a', :href => "delete"  ,
                                       :content => "delete")  
      end
    end
```

Here's the code I'm testing.  It's from views/hunts.html.erb

```
    <h1>All Hunts</h1>

    <%= will_paginate %>

    <ul>
      <% @hunts.each do |hunt| %>
            <li>
          <%= link_to hunt.name, hunt %>
          <% if current_user && current_user.admin? %>
            | <%= link_to "edit", edit_hunt_path(hunt) %>
            | <%= link_to "delete", hunt, :method => :delete, :confirm => "You   
                          sure?",  :title => "Delete #{hunt.name}" %>


          <% end %>
        </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
    <%= will_paginate %>

    <%= link_to( "Create New Hunt", '/hunts/new') %>
```

And here's the relevant part of the hunt controller.

```
class HuntsController < ApplicationController

  def index
     @title = "All Hunts"
     @hunts = Hunt.paginate(:page => params[:page])
  end

    ....
end
```

When I run rspec, this is what appears.

```
    </li>
            <li>
      <a href="/hunts/30">---
   - optio
   - et
   - sunt
   </a>
        | <a href="/hunts/30/edit">edit</a>
        | <a href="/hunts/30" data-confirm="You sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow" title="Delete ---
   - optio
   - et
   - sunt
   ">delete</a>
```

Finally, here's my factories.rb file.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:name)  { |n| "Person #{n}" }
    sequence(:email) { |n| "person_#{n}@example.com"}   
    password "foobar"
    password_confirmation "foobar"

    factory :admin do
      admin true
    end
  end

  factory :hunt do
    name "Test Hunt" 
  end
end
```

UPDATE:  So I dropped the "a" from the original tests.  I also rewrote the test so that it looks at each hunt on page 1.

```
      describe "for users who are admins" do
        before(:each) do
            admin = FactoryGirl.create(:user, :email => "admin@example.com", :admin => true)
            test_sign_in(admin)
        end

        it "should show edit link" do
          get 'index'
          Hunt.paginate(:page => 1).each do |hunt|
            response.should have_selector(:href => "edit",
                                           :content => "edit")
          end 
        end

        it "should show delete link" do
          get 'index'
          Hunt.paginate(:page => 1).each do |hunt|
            response.should have_selector(:href => "delete",
                                           :content => "delete")  
          end
        end
      end
```

So now I've got a different error:

```
HuntsController GET 'index' for users who are admins should show edit link
 Failure/Error: response.should have_selector(:href => "edit",
 Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError:
   unexpected '{' after ''
```

I tried googling this error, but haven't had much luck.  Seen it before?  I'm not sure what syntax I'm messing up.

Comment: In your have_selector, is `:href => "edit"` right?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's correct. But I changed things up without much success.  I added the revised code to the main section.

Comment: Is it valid to exclude the name of the selector? Have you tried wrapping your hash in braces, something like: `response.should have_selector('a', {:href => "delete", :content => "delete"})`  ?

Comment: I revised the code to per your suggestion.  The tests still fail, now for a different reason. Rspec says "Failure/Error: response.should have_selector('a', {:href => "edit", :content => "edit"})
       expected following output to contain a <a href='edit'>edit</a> tag:"  and this is what appears:       `<ul>
       <li>
          <a href="/hunts/1">---
       - est
       </a>
           | <a href="/hunts/1/edit">edit</a>
            | <a href="/hunts/1" data-confirm="You sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow" title="Delete ---
       - est
       ">delete</a>`

Comment: FYI--I only changed one of the failing tests (edit, instead of edit and delete)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you change the selector to the following:

```
it "should show an 'edit' link" do
  get :index
  ...
  response.should have_selector('a', :href => edit_hunt_path(hunt), :content => 'edit')
  ...
end
```

If you are using Capybara then you can simply use have_link() instead of have_selector().

Comment: That code worked great for the edit test, but not with the delete test.  I think it's because the link is setup differently.  (See view above.) Ultimately, the link is to the individual hunt (not a delete path).  So I get a no method error when trying to copy the code that worked for the edit test.  Any idea who to best ID the particular hunt to be deleted (e.g. "hunts/7")?

Comment: You should be able to use hunt_path(hunt) (since its very similar to the 'show' action but it uses the DELETE method instead of GET.

So the check will be similar to this:

response.should have_selector('a', :href => hunt_path(hunt), :content => 'delete')